# Error when trying to use a .docx file for the Merge

Tags: visual-studio, aspose.words

Working Visual Studio, using Merge Refactor to file in a online form and merge the data into a word document, when using a .doc file, everything works fine, but when I try to use a .docx file, I get the following error, any assistance would be great!

Cannot find target of relationship 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument'
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find
>   target of relationship
>   'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument'
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 85:          var selectedDocumentPath =
>   DocumentDDL.Items[DocumentDDL.SelectedIndex].Value;
>
> Line 86:          var ext =
>   System.IO.Path.GetExtension(selectedDocumentPath);
>
> Line 87:             Document doc = new
>   Document(selectedDocumentPath);
>
> Line 88:
>
> Line 89:          var mergeData = ConstructMergeData();

Comment: Have you tried [latest version of Aspose.Words for .NET](https://downloads.aspose.com/words/net) i.e. 18.10? In case the problem still remains, please ZIP and Upload your **1)** input Word document (DOC and DOCX files) and **2)** a simple console application (_source code without compilation errors_) to Dropbox and share the Download link here for testing. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to help. Here is the link you download the files - http://douguhler.com/files. Tried updating the lastest Aspose.Words for .NET but it didn't correct the issue. I know very little about the software.  Any help would be great appreciated!

Comment: I downloaded the file from the shared link; but, when i tried to open/extract 'ApplicationEval--uhlerdj-uhlerdj.zip' file, it says, "The archive is either in unknown format or damaged". Please check and fix this issue.